# Python - features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s with high level tf APIs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor, tensorflow-estimator

I want to train, evaluate the accuracy and eventually predict with my model. This is my first time using high level APIs such as tf.estimator.

I'm getting a value error from `estimator.train(train_input_fn)`:

*'ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor's. Given type: '*

I'm not sure what is going on here. My model is taking 3 inputs and producing a binary output from one neuron.

Before this error I was getting an error about the requested shape not equal to the actual shape, or something along those lines. I fixed it by reducing the batchSize down to 1, instead of 100. I'm sure this isn't going to do so well when it comes to training though.

Any ideas? Heres my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/blairburns/Documents/DeepLearning/BackgroundColourPredictor/Dataset/Testing/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/blairburns/Documents/DeepLearning/BackgroundColourPredictor/Dataset/Training/')
#other files
from TestDataNormaliser import *
from TrainDataNormaliser import *

learning_rate = 0.01
trainingIteration = 15
batchSize = 1
displayStep = 2

#Layers using tf.layers
def get_logits(features):
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(features, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2, 1, activation=None)
    a = l3
    return a


#cost function

def get_loss(a, labels):
    #cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(a)))
    return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=a, labels=labels)
    #cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean((l3 - y)**2)
    #cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(a))-tf.reduce_sum((1-y)*tf.log(1-a))


#optimizer

def get_train_op(loss):
    learning_rate = 1e-3
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate)
    return optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())


#training

####

def get_inputs(feature_data, label_data, batch_size, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (feature_data, label_data))

    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(feature_data))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    a = get_logits(features)
    loss = get_loss(a, labels)
    train_op = get_train_op(loss)
    predictions = tf.greater(a, 0)
    accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode,
    loss=loss,
    train_op=train_op,
    eval_metric_ops={'Accuracy': accuracy},
    predictions=predictions
    )

def train_input_fn():
    return get_inputs(
    trainArrayValues,
    trainArrayLabels,
    batchSize
    )

def eval_input_fn():
    return get_inputs(
    testArrayValues,
    testArrayLabels,
    batchSize,
    n_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False
    )

model_dir = './savedModel'

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[model_fn, model_dir])
#estimator.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=1)
estimator.train(train_input_fn)
estimator.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[model_fn, model_dir])
```

You need to set the `feature_columns` argument to an array of feature columns. A feature column tells the estimator about the data you're feeding it.

It looks like all your input data is numeric, so I'd call  `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` to create your feature column(s). The documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column). For example, the following code creates a numeric feature column containing x-coordinates:

```
xcol = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x')
```

If all your estimator needs are x-coordinates, then you could create the estimator with the following code:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[xcol])
```

Comment: Thank you, what do I replace ‘xcol’ with?

Comment: If you create a feature column named `xcol`, you'd add it to an array and assign the array to the `feature_columns` argument in the estimator's constructor. I updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Still getting the same error from estimator.train(train_input_fn)

Comment: You need to set the output of your train/test functions equal to a dictionary that matches feature column names to the data. For example, if you create a feature column named "x", the output of your train/test functions needs to provide a dictionary that matches "x" to the appropriate data. Read the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/feature_columns.